# Python Requests - No connection adapters

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm using the [Requests: HTTP for Humans](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library and I got this weird error and I don't know what is mean.

```
No connection adapters were found for '192.168.1.61:8080/api/call'
```

Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 676, accepted):

You need to include the protocol scheme:

```
'http://192.168.1.61:8080/api/call'
```

Without the `http://` part, `requests` has no idea how to connect to the remote server.

Note that the protocol scheme must be all lowercase; if your URL starts with `HTTP://` for example, it won’t find the `http://` connection adapter either.

Answer (score 51):

One more reason, maybe your url include some hiden characters, such as '\n'.

If you define your url like below, this exception will raise:

```
url = '''
http://google.com
'''
```

because there are '\n' hide in the string. The url in fact become:

```
\nhttp://google.com\n
```

Comment: Or if your url is accidentally a tuple because of a trailing comma `url = self.base_url % endpoint,`

Comment: @ChristianLong is there any way to convert a  string to proper url? Like, can you tell me, what are you doing in your comment?

Comment: for me it was the ` " "` not sure why, but at some point my single-quoted URL became single-quoted and then double-quoted (maybe pyCharm, maybe github, at some point it must got filtered that way. I had "http://google.com" and then it became " ' http://google.com ' " - after making it just a string it worked again.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I received this error ***when I refactored a url, leaving an erroneous comma*** thus converting my url from a string into a tuple.

**My exact error message:**

```
    741         # Nothing matches :-/
--> 742         raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
    743 
    744     def close(self):

InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "('https://api.foo.com/data',)"
```

Here's how that error came to be born:

```py
# Original code:
response = requests.get("api.%s.com/data" % "foo", headers=headers)

# --------------
# Modified code (with bug!)
api_name = "foo"
url = f"api.{api_name}.com/data",  # !!! Extra comma doesn't belong here!
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


# --------------
# Solution: Remove erroneous comma!
api_name = "foo"
url = f"api.{api_name}.com/data"  # No extra comma!
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115328/python-requests-no-connection-adapters#comment79696581_38810597) by [christian-long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456550/christian-long)

Your url may accidentally be a tuple because of a trailing comma

```
url = self.base_url % endpoint,
```

Make sure it is a string

Comment: changing the tuple to a string gave me the same error. Can you give an example?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by changing to string. I meant `url = self.base_url % endpoint` without the comma

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used default `url` for method

```
def call_url(url: str = "https://www.google.com"):
```

and `url` attr was overridden by some method to `/some/url`