# InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url) in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

This is my first time on webscraping , so dont get hard on me. I am learning to scrape the data out of site but I am getting the following error:

> raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" %
>   url) InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for
>   '('http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/good', 'html.parser')'

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url=('http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/good',"html.parser")
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)
links=soup.find_all("a")
```

I have seen other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115328/python-requests-no-connection-adapters/%22answers%22) and notice i need to put `http://`, I have done that but to no avail.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'html.parser'` parameter should be passed to `BeautifulSoup` not `requests.get`. Passing it to the latter makes the `url` *nonsensical* to `requests.get`:

```
url = 'http://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/good'
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: I still get this error `BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser")`

Comment: @froost1999  Yes. However, you should pass the `'html.parser'` parameter to `soup` as shown in the answer to suppress the warning

Comment: @froost1999 Well it isn't a thing. Are you getting results from `soup.find_all("a")`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127450/discussion-between-froost1999-and-moses-koledoye).