# error reading URL using python, how to fix

Tags: python, python-requests

```
import requests
data = 'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\dashboard\dom.html'
response = requests.get(data)
print (response.json())
```

Error receives as

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I have tried making as `data = (r'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\dashboard\dom.html')` gives error as

```
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for url
```

Comment: I think the backslashes in the string might be the issue. Try adding `r` in front to make it a raw string.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115328/python-requests-no-connection-adapters and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347791/unicode-error-unicodeescape-codec-cant-decode-bytes-cannot-open-text-file

Comment: can't you simply read the data via reading file /

Comment: Isn't requests only for HTTP protocol?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the type of slash.
Replace it with this `/`.
your code will become:

```
import requests
data = 'C:/Users/abc/Desktop/dashboard/dom.html'
response = requests.get(data)
print (response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read local files in requests, by default you can only use http or https protocols. However, you have the ability to write custom adapters, but the best way is to read the file normally instead of using requests.

```
with open("file.json") as fh:
    print(json.load(fh))
```