# How to interact with Influxdb running on a remote Windows 10 PC in a local network?

Tags: python, network-programming, influxdb

I'd like to make a post request by whatever method to write a new point into Influxdb database called `my_db`, running on another PC in my local network. The PC with Influxdb 1.8 runs on Windows 10. So far I tried to use Python in this way:

```
import requests
requests.post(url="192.168.x.x:8086/write?db=my_db", data=my_data)
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '192.168.x.x:8086/write?db=my_db'
```

Is there some kind of setup to be done in order to enable remote connections? Please excuse my ignorance, but I'm not very comfortable with the networking stuff. If possible, I'd like to avoid any kind authentication.

Comment: Add the schema to the URL, e.g. `http://` or `https://`!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests - No connection adapters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115328/python-requests-no-connection-adapters)