# Installing libmxl2 into virtual environment OSX

Tags: python, macos, lxml, homebrew, conda

I've already read the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019942/why-cant-i-get-pip-install-lxml-to-work-within-a-virtualenv), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856468/how-to-install-libxml2-in-virtualenv) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473197/how-to-install-libxml2-dev-libxslt-dev-on-mac-os).  Basically, I'm using a conda environment and I want to install `lxml`.  When I run `pip install lxml` I get a long error message that includes `Failed building wheel for lxml` and `error minimum required version of libxslt is 1.1.23`.  This makes me believe I need to install `libxml2` and `libxslt` into the virtual environment (they are already installed on the system *outside* the environment.)

So for Linux, I read in one of the linked answers that I should run:

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

I tried to adapt that to OSX and homebrew.  Inside the conda environment I ran:

```
brew install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev
```

and got:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "libxml2-dev"
```

How do I get homebrew to install `libxml2` into the conda environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev on Mac os](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473197/how-to-install-libxml2-dev-libxslt-dev-on-mac-os)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate.  That solution didn't work for me (got the same error as above `minimum required version of libxslt is 1.1.23`).

Comment: Depending on the distro it can sometimes be `libxml2-devel libxslt-devel`...

Comment: brew does not distinguish between runtime and development packages usually. When you install `libxml2` it will install the runtime libs as well as the headers to link to it as well. You will just have to make sure your application links to this library then instead of the system default one (which seems to be too old for your use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel foolish.  I ran

```
conda install lxml
```

and that worked.  I had been thinking only about using `pip`.

If you are reading this and want to use `pip` and `brew` instead of `conda`, I believe you might need to create a symlink to the correct keg-only installation of `libxml2` and `libxslt`.