# How fix my error when i try install libxml2 on Windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am on Windows 7 using Python 3.8 when i use command to install that appear this:

```
Collecting libxml2-python3
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/97/a2ecf6c5b291799dbd4
0b3d041d89b0ecdb1b43c8c2503e27991325851cd/libxml2-python3-2.9.5.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Ivoyko\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.
exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Ivoyko\
\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d_yll6qf\\libxml2-python3\\setup.py'"'"'; __f
ile__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Ivoyko\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d_yll6qf\\libxml
2-python3\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);cod
e=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __
file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Ivoyko\AppData\Local\Tem
p\pip-install-d_yll6qf\libxml2-python3\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Ivoyko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d_yll6qf\libxml2-py
thon3\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    failed to find headers for libxml2: update includes_dir
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check th
e logs for full command output.
```

I installed some stuff from Visual Studio 2019 as VS14 but i cant fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cannot Install libxml2 in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880914/cannot-install-libxml2-in-virtualenv)

Comment: really no bc that dude its using fedora, sudo, yum or apt-get dont work on my windows stuff.